# The usage of preposition "on"

Tags: prepositions, dates

In my grammar book, I have these example statements.

1. We were married July 21, 2000, in New York.
2. We were married on July 21 in New York.

Is it a rule not to use "on" when the year is included to specify a date?

Comment: Yes, just as your book has indicated.

Comment: No, I don't think there is any rule like that.  You can just as easily say "We were married on August 30th, 2009."  @Abbasi - Do you have any reference for this rule?

Comment: @stangdon: Their *grammar book* itself is in fact a reference. You may also type "on or in for dates" on Google. I found [this](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adverbials/adverbials-time/time-and-dates) that can be considered as a reference.

Comment: @Abbasi: But your link does not support your claim; it doesn't say anything about complete dates.

Comment: @Abbasi: I don't see how *in" can serve as a preposition for dates.  One doesn't get married *in* July 21. One gets married *on* July 21(st). *In* works only if the date is not specified, as in *married in July*.

Comment: @Abbasi - Their grammar book is a reference?! The whole point of this question is that the book doesn't state that rule, or presumably prosseek wouldn't be asking about it.  Yes, we say "in 2009" and "on July 30th", but there is nothing on the page you cite that says "don't use *on* if you're using a year as well as a date".  I'm sorry, but you are just wrong about this one.

Answer (score 1):

The *on* is permitted, but optional, in both cases.

Personally I find it more natural to use *on*; the *on*-less version sounds quite formal to me. But the "were married" construction *also* sounds quite formal to me — I would have written, "We got married on July 21, 2000, in New York" — so maybe the formal style is intentional.

(For what it's worth, I'm an American in my thirties. It wouldn't surprise me if British speakers and/or older speakers would feel differently about either of these.)

Comment: I am British. I would always use "on" there, and omitting it sounds utterly American to me.